# How can I do a Depth First Search (DFS) on a data table like this?

Tags: c++

So I am having trouble finding a way to implement DFS on this table. The user will enter a start state and end state. It will be great if someone can give me some ideas as to go about solving this problem.

```
Enter Start State: 
01
Enter End State: 
70
```

This would be the correct answer returned.

01 -> 71 -> 73 -> 03 -> 00 -> 70

```
# is the fist column
```

Starts at #01 and goes to the first not visited position 71 then go to #71 and checks the first non repeating position being 73 then goes to #73 and checks first non repeating position in 03 and then goes to #03 and checks first non repeating position which is 00 and goes to #00 and find 70 the final state.

```
    #  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
   00       70      03      00      00      00      00      00      00      
   01       71      03      01      00      01      01      01      10      
   02       72      03      02      00      02      02      02      20      
   03       73      03      03      00      03      03      03      30      
   10       70      13      00      10      10      01      10      10      
   11       71      13      01      10      11      02      11      20      
   12       72      13      02      10      03      12      12      30      
   13       73      13      03      10      13      13      13      40      
   20       70      23      00      20      20      02      20      20      
   21       71      23      01      20      03      21      21      30      
   22       72      23      02      20      13      22      22      40      
   23       73      23      03      20      23      23      23      50      
   30       70      33      00      30      03      30      30      30      
   31       71      33      01      30      13      31      31      40      
   32       72      33      02      30      23      32      32      50      
   33       73      33      03      30      33      33      33      60      
   40       70      43      00      40      13      40      40      40      
   41       71      43      01      40      23      41      41      50      
   42       72      43      02      40      33      42      42      60      
   43       73      43      03      40      43      43      70      43      
   50       70      53      00      50      23      50      50      50      
   51       71      53      01      50      33      51      51      60      
   52       72      53      02      50      43      52      70      52      
   53       73      53      03      50      53      53      71      53      
   60       70      63      00      60      33      60      60      60      
   61       71      63      01      60      43      61      70      61      
   62       72      63      02      60      53      62      71      62      
   63       73      63      03      60      63      63      72      63      
   70       70      73      00      70      43      70      70      70      
   71       71      73      01      70      53      71      71      71      
   72       72      73      02      70      63      72      72      72      
   73       73      73      03      70      73      73      73      73
```

Comment: This is just a graph where each node has 8 children; any standard DFS implementation should do the job.